# Showing that $n\sin(x/n)$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence

I know the version of this question with closed interval has been asked to death in this site, but how about if the function sequence $f_n(x) = n\sin(x/n)$ is considered over $\mathbb{R}$? At first I thought that the sequence would not converge to the limiting function $f(x) = x$, since at the points $x_n = n\pi$, $f(x_n) = n\pi$, but $f_n(x_n) = 0$. But is this sufficient to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\{\left|f(x) - f_n(x)\right|\} \neq 0$?

Comment: Use your considerations to compute $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f(x) - f_n(x)|$.

Comment: Yes. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800874/uniform-convergence-of-supremum for example. Note, it suffices to show that the limit of the suprema either is nonzero or does not exist. When I see a limit expression described as "$\neq 0$" I sometimes wonder if a writer is still requiring a limit to exist. It's definitely not necessary (or the case) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
In fact
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb N:\sup_{x\in \mathbb R}\{|f(x) - f_n(x)|\} = \sup_{x\in \mathbb R}\{|x-n\sin(x/n)|\} =\ "\infty"
$$
i.e. there is no supremum for any $n \in \mathbb N$ and so the limit
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\{\left|f(x) - f_n(x)\right|\}
$$
is meaningless